# Does the Chrome console execute things the same way as Visual Studio Code?

Tags: javascript, node.js, console, web-crawler, puppeteer

I want to crawl the web for discount links, so I've done this. When I test my code on the console, the `data2` (which is an array of links that I've stored ) was correct as I expected. `data2` only lists the links that have a discount.

[image: This code written on Chrome console]

But when I run on console of VSCode, I ended up with the different result (`data2` now has all of the links, not only the discount ones).

[image: This code written on VisualStudioCode]

Can you tell me the difference? I doubt that my "if" condition in VScode cannot be adapted which leads to this.

> **Note:** THE CODE I RUN ON CHROME IS COPIED FROM THE VSCODE, THE LOGIC IS EXACTLY THE SAME.

Comment: `console.log` the `document`, see the difference. Your desktop browser may (most likely) differ from one you are using to crawl. Then server may be generate different `document`s for each of them.

Comment: Please post your code as text, not inside a painting.

Comment: Don't `await result` in your return statement, `result` is not a promise

Answer (score 0):

There are a few issues with your code.

First of all, the page you are attempting to visit loads its content dynamically, so you may want to wait for the elements specified by selector string to be added to DOM using [`page.waitForSelector()`](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#pagewaitforselectorselector-options):

```
await page.waitForSelector('#app > div > div.container > div.now-list-restautants > div > div > a > div.info-restaurant > p > i');
```

Additionally, inside [`page.evaluate()`](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#pageevaluatepagefunction-args), the variable `jq` is not defined:

```
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(jq); // jq is not defined
```

Furthermore, you are unnecessarily awaiting `result` twice. You can just return `result`:

```
return result;
```

Finally, make sure you are using [`browser.close()`](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#browserclose) after you have finished scraping the links:

```
await browser.close();
```

---

The rest of the issues listed below are related to style and not necessarily functionality.

You should use [`let`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let) and [`const`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/const) instead of [`var`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var) whenever possible ([source](https://github.com/airbnb/javascript#references)):

```
const arr = ... // good
var arr = ...   // bad
```

If you are going to convert an iterable object to an array, use the [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax), instead of [`Array.from()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from) ([source](https://github.com/airbnb/javascript#arrays--from-iterable)):

```
[...elements]        // good
Array.from(elements) // bad
```

You can obtain the [`href`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a#attr-href) attribute from elements using the [`href`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLHyperlinkElementUtils/href) property, and, therefore, you do not need to use [`getAttribute('href')`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getAttribute):

```
element.querySelector('.item-content').href                 // good
element.querySelector('.item-content').getAttribute('href') // bad
```

---

Here is a full working example:

```
'use strict';

const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

let scrape = async () => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({headless: false});
  const page = await browser.newPage();

  await page.goto('https://www.now.vn/ho-chi-minh/food/danh-sach-dia-diem-phuc-vu-ca-phe,nuoc-ep-sinh-to,16,70-giao-tan-noi');

  await page.waitForSelector('#app > div > div.container > div.now-list-restautants > div > div > a > div.info-restaurant > p > i');

  const result = await page.evaluate(() => {
    // document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(jq);
    const data2 = [];
    const elements = document.querySelector('#app > div > div.container > div.now-list-restautants > div').children;
    const arr = [...elements];
    const regex = '';

    arr.shift();

    arr.forEach((element, index) => {
      const tagi = document.querySelector('#app > div > div.container > div.now-list-restautants > div > div:nth-child(' + (index + 2) + ') > a > div.info-restaurant > p > i');

      if (element.contains(tagi)) {
        data2.push(element.querySelector('.item-content').href);
      }
    });

    return data2;
  });

  await browser.close();

  return result;
};

scrape().then(value => {
  console.log(value);
});
```